# How to handle dynamic id

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to explore log In button xpath with this site https://www.componence.com/login, by just recording and play back.Then I tried to get it through firepath and chrome browser default xpath copier.

But it looks like every time submit button xpath get changed with page load. I got following xpath for "Sign IN" button.

```
.//*[@id='yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1487250469606_202']
.//*[@id='yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1487251369606_202']
.//*[@id='yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1487250229606_202']
.//*[@id='yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1487254369606_202']
```

Can you please help me to retrieve correct xpath of Sign IN button which I can use with selenium IDE?

Answer (score 2):

You can use below `XPath` to handle dynamic `id`:

```
//button[starts-with(@id, "yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_")]
```

But better solution is to use text content of element:

```
//button[normalize-space(text())="Sign In"]
```

Answer (score 2):

I will have to disagree with the second statement of @Andersson, since it will work for `.com` but not for `.nl`.

As I see the site has a second language and my opinion is to avoid using selectors based on text on a multi-language environment.

Also as I see the `id` seems does not have a meaningful value, in this case try to identify a unique parent section and go from there.

One option for css/xpath would be:

css: `form.sign-in-form button`

xpath: `//form[contains(@class, 'sign-in-form')]//button`

Comment: And I can disagree with you :) As QA I think that if one wants to complete authorization on English version of web-site with  `driver.get("https://www.componence.com")` he certainly doesn't want to get Dutch version of Login page

Comment: Yes, you are right, also using text he can also check if translation is ok, this can be a double check :)